# formula changing the original cell's value

Tags: excel

It might be a strange question, but is it possible to use a formula that changes the original cell's value to the outcome of that formula?

for example: I fill in C5 "10", and I inserted a formula there that multiplies it by 5, so the value in C5 will change to "50"

of course it mustn't make a loop, multiplying every new value by 5 so the cell will soon be too small for the number. (10)*5)*5)*5)*5)*5....
only once.

I hope this is possible although I don't think so.

Cheers,

Bart.

Comment: You have to clarify. You want a macro that multiplies a cell by 5?

Comment: I'm not sure really. if that means the cell value multiplies by 5 once, then yes. Never worked with macro's before.

Comment: `I'm not sure really.` then no one can help you.

Comment: Why not just create a section for your numbers, and just use references? Why do you want to "overwrite" the cell with a formula? Also, when changing "10", will you enter the cell and type the formula you're looking for? Do you know what you want in the end? Please expand on your overall idea, so we can avoid an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're not sure what you want, then we aren't either.

Comment: @BruceWayne I pictured a button click that will multiple a cell by 5. OP is confused so eh.

Comment: to clarify: I wasn't sure about the macro. since I never used it before or what it's used for.

the idea is that I fill in a value in one cell, and that same cell does a function and changes its value to the outcome once. 

but I found an alternative solution thanks to BruceWayne's comment. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we enter values in cell **C5** and want to have the value automatically multiplied by 5 each time we enter a new value.

Place the following Event Macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C5 As Range
    Set C5 = Range("C5")
    If Intersect(Target, C5) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        C5 = 5 * C5
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**